Executing a Long-Running Stored Procedure in Azure SQL Server with Spring Boot
I need to run a stored procedure on my Azure SQL Server that takes about 20 minutes to complete. Normally, I use Spring to perform this kind of operation:
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    @Procedure(procedureName = "my_procedure")
    void my_procedure();
}

private void importProcedure(){
    repository.my_procedure();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout = 6)
public void import_procedure_conferimenti() {
    log.info("Start");
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::importprocedure);
    future.thenAccept(result -> {
        log.info("Finish");
    }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        log.error("Error", throwable);
        return null; // Return a default value in case of an error
    });
}

My Spring settings are:
datasource:
  driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://db:port;database=db-name;user=user;password=pwd;...;socketTimeout=60000
  hikari:
    minimum-idle: 10
    maximum-pool-size: 50

However, using this approach, I get a SocketTimeout error because of the socketTimeout=60000 parameter in the URL.
I have read a lot about this kind of problem, and I know it depends on the socket timeout that waits for the response before getting the result, as discussed here.
I resolved the problem using the following approach:
public Object executeProcedure(String procedureCall, int networkTimeoutMillis, int queryTimeoutSeconds) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Object result = null;
    try {
        connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        connection.setNetworkTimeout(null, networkTimeoutMillis);

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(procedureCall);
        preparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(queryTimeoutSeconds);
        boolean hasResultSet = preparedStatement.execute();
        if (hasResultSet) {
            resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                result = resultSet.getObject(1);  // Return the result as an Object
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error during procedure execution: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, dataSource);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

This works: fantastic!
However, I'm unsure if this is the best approach since I need to specify a custom timeout for each procedure. What I want is to:

Call the stored procedure.

close the connection to avoid socketTimeout

Receive the response as it is being processed.

Get the result when it is finished (polling?).


I don't know if this is possible. I've read many questions on this topic 1 2, but none seem to work in my case: How to return from a long-running procedure call in Spring MVC.
Additional info:

Spring Boot: 2.3
Java version: 1.8


That's not how sql server works, if you close the connection, the execution is aborted (usually). Also, there's no good way of getting results asyncroniously even if you manage to kick off a job etc, unless you use some magic stuff. You'll have to wait for it to finish, or start a job and then poll something to see when it finishes, but in that case, you might as well execute it yourself. Also, i've worked with sql server a lot and never used socketTimeout, why do you need it

so I have to specify the time for every procedure?

Why not just increase the default timeout in your connection string or in spring declaration and remove the silly socketthing

Also, perhaps check why procedure is taking so long and why a user needs to wait 20 minutes for it

because I'm concerned about frontend response times when calling other APIs. These should not exceed one minute

the user do not wait for 20 min because it is async. The response from controller is fast. So in the backgroud the procedure take time 20 min. For the procedure performance I don't know exactly why but it is out of my scope

OK, then perhaps your approach ain't bad. You could also set the timeout on spring methods specifically (either fast, slow or no timeout at all), but i don't know how big change that is.

mm thanks for your feedback. I appreciate it :)
